# Как правильно писать: "8 академических часа" или "часов"?

Tags: согласование, падежи, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Как правильно писать: "8 академических часа" или "часов"?

Answer (score 3):

Как и для любых числительных в русском языке:

- 1 академический час
- 2,3,4 академических часа
- 5,6,7,...,20 академических часов
- 21 академический час
- 22,23,24 академических часа
- 25,26,27,28,29,30 академических часов
- 31 академический час

и так далее.

Comment: 5 и более, но не все подряд! Для всех чисел, больших, чем 20, и оканчивающихся на 1 (21, 31 и т. п.) - *час*; оканчивающихся на 2, 3, 4 (22, 23, 24, 32, 33, 34 и т. п.) - *часа*; для всех остальных - *часов*.

Comment: Исправил соответственно.

Answer (score 3):

Числительные по правилам русского языка согласуются с существительными таким образом:

**Один** (одна, одно) — именительный падеж (**час**, мужчина, собака, окно);
**два** (две), три, четыре — родительный (**часа**, мужчины, собаки, окна);
**пять** - **двадцать** — родительный падеж множественного числа (**часов**, мужчин, собак, окон).

*В числительных, которые больше двадцати, согласованию подлежит **только число единиц*** (число десятков, сотен, тысяч и т. д. не имеет значения):

двадцать **одна собака**, сорок **четыре окна**, пятьдесят **семь мужчин**, девяносто **восемь часов**; 2368 академических часов.
[**числительные**](http://nekin.info/math/imya_chislitelnoye.htm)

Comment: Я бы сказал, последняя фраза ничего не добавляет к предыдущей. "После 20 согласованию подлежит (только) число единиц" -  это уже подразумевает, что все остальное не имеет значения.

Comment: Но все равно +1

Comment: Спасибо! Мне хотелось пояснить так, чтобы уже не возникало _никаких_ дополнительных вопросов. P.S. А Вы считаете, что необходимо подправить?

Comment: Пожалуй, стоит оставить (для  лучшего усвоения материала). Первоначально меня смутило то, что "не имеет значения" не относится к десяткам, а это путает. Я бы как-то переписал текст, например так: "В числительных, которые больше двадцати,  согласованию подлежит только число единиц, а число десятков, сотен, тысяч и т. д. не имеет значения."

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Я объединила "всяческие" цифры в одно предложение.