# 273 инвалида или инвалидов?

Tags: склонение, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать "...500 человек, в т.ч. 
273 инвалидА или инвалидОВ"?

Comment: А вы бы как это произнесли? Вот так же и пишите.

Comment: См. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434967/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-8-%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2/434975#434975), например.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **500 человек, в т.ч. 273 инвалидА**

Числительные **два, три, четыре**, а также **составные** числительные на два, три, четыре сочетаются с существительными **в форме ед.** числа: два, три, четыре человека/инвалида.

**Особые правила** сочетания числительных  два, три, четыре с существительными в единственном числе связаны **с исторической грамматикой.**